# excel vba: can't set cells formula from a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set a formula using a macro. I've come to a point where my macro creates a string with formula that I want to insert but I get an error when I try to set the formula. Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Function AutoFormula(blocks As Range, target As Range)
    Dim blockedArr() As String
    Dim cellValue As String
    Dim ret As String
    Dim i As Integer

    'sprawdzenie zakresu
    If (blocks.Cells.Count > 1) Then
        AutoFormula = "Tylko 1 komórka jako parametr!"
        Exit Function
    End If

     'wczytanie komorki
    cellValue = blocks.Cells(1, 1).Value

    'split
    blockedArr = Split(cellValue, ",")

    ret = "=WYSZUKAJ.PIONOWO(E7;$E$2:$G$5;3;FAŁSZ)"

    For i = LBound(blockedArr, 1) To UBound(blockedArr, 1)
        ret = ret + "+SUMA.JEŻELI(A7:A1000;" + blockedArr(i) + ";G7:G1000)"
    Next i

    target.Cells(1, 1).Value = ret
End Function

Sub auto()
    Call AutoFormula(Worksheets("reorganizacja").Range("D7"), Worksheets("reorganizacja").Range("G7"))
End Sub
```

I get a

> Runtime error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

in the last line of AutoFormula function. I have no idea what's that supposed to mean except that 'there is some error related to something'.
Anyways, I also tried using `target.Formula = ret` but it's the same case.

Comment: `target.Cells(1, 1).FormulaLocal = ret`

Comment: Thank you! That solved the case!

Answer (score 0):

When you fill a cell with `.formula` using VBA you have to use the English version of the functions you use. So WYSZUKAJ.PIONOWO is `VLOOKUP` and SUMA.JEŻELI is `SUMIF` (according to Google translate). Oh and FAŁSZ is probably `False`.

Comment: That didn't help unfortunately - I'm still getting the same error in the same spot.
Actually the other solution worked and if I use english names I get an error in the spreadsheet itself as it's unable to parse the formula.

Comment: Like Scott Craner says you also need to use comma instead of semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Scott's comment is the proper solution - using FormulaLocal.
However, now having read about differences with Formula and FormulaLocal, I don't understand why Formula wouldn't work with english versions of the excel functions...

Anyways got it to work, thank you Scott!

Comment: It will work.  You need to also change the `;` to `,`.

Comment: `change the ; to ,`  Exactly. I overlooked that and should have added it to my answer.

Comment: depends on locale - in polish Excel uses `;` to separate params instead of `,`

Comment: Doesn't matter, inside `.formula` you always use comma.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not very descriptive (when are they right?), it basically means there is a SYNTAX ERROR in your formula. In your case it may have to do with your local.

I suggest simplifying the formula then adding complexity to help reveal where the problem is. Or if it's a local issue you can try using .FomulaLocal as Scott Craner suggested.

Another good idea is to MsgBox your string variable that holds the formula; this will make it easier to see what the formula looks like after doing string concatenations.